# Disable DNS IPv6 lookup in gstreamer

Tags: linux, dns, gstreamer, ipv6

Initial problem: when reading http streams with `gstreamer` (`gst-launch` command) on a specific customer network, I observed very often (not always) a 5 seconds initial delay before the stream starts loading.

After some investigation I found out (with wireshark) that this was caused by DNS resolution issues, and specifically the AAAA queries (IPv6) which failed (no response) at a high frequency (on this network specifically) and caused a wait-and-retry after 5 seconds.

I observed the same issue when using "wget", but not with "wget -4" because it does not perform the AAAA queries.

Changing the network infrastructure is not an option. Therefore, I'd like to know if it's possible to somehow skip the AAAA / IPv6 DNS lookup when running `gstreamer`, just like wget's "-4" option.

Comment: Which element of the gstreamer pipeline it is?

Comment: @Velkan I assume it is udpsrc

Comment: In year 2017, disabling IPv6 to ignore broken network configuration is also not an option. You don't need to change your network infrastructure, you need to fix it.

Comment: You could prefer IPv4 DNS lookups on your linux system, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/32298/prefer-a-ipv4-dns-lookups-before-aaaaipv6-lookups - if this is a possibility for you.

Comment: @datacosmos I think that IPv4 DNS lookup is already prefered but it does not prevent the IPv6 DNS requests.

Comment: another imperfect solution would be to disable the ipv6 support of the kernel completely, see http://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-disable-ipv6-on-linux/